# Tree conflict on update Update

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting this while taking update in xcode.

"The operation could not be performed because of one or more tree conflicts.
The file XYZ.xcscmblueprint had a tree conflict."

How could I get the path of ".xcscmblueprint" file in xcode.
What to do to solve this problem.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Can you give more information? Are you using Git to pull?

Comment: A has commit and B tried to take update of what A has done in XYZ project. SVN to pull.

Comment: There is a conflict in the project file, so you need to pull using the command line or a GUI tool like SourceTree (Free) and manually resolve the conflict in a text editor or diff tool. - Online source

Comment: Any alternative, as because I have my work in project file which i need  to commit after update, So i can't pull now :(